# Is class func possible to return class itself?

Tags: swift

Is  class func  possible to return class itself? And what does the currentUser function use for?Thanks

```
class FUser: FObject {
     class func currentUser() -> FUser {
       if let dictionary = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "CurrentUser") as? [String: Any] {
          return FUser(path: "User", dictionary: dictionary)
       }
    return FUser(path: "User")
 }

class FObject: NSObject {
    init(path: String, subpath: String?) {
      super.init()
      pathX = path
      subpathX = subpath
   }

 convenience init(path: String) {
    self.init(path: path, subpath: nil)
   }
 }
```

Comment: The method returns an **instance** of the class.

Comment: What you want it to return? What do you want to so with it?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean singleton object, then this is the way to do it:

```
class ClassA {

    static let shared = ClassA()

    private init() {
          // Init
    }
}
```

Since `init` is private, there will only be one instance.

Answer (score 0):

First possible option is that you want to create *static factory method*. Yes, you can do this. Just return **new** instance of `FUser` object

```
class FUser: FObject {
    private override init() {...} // then make your init `private`
    class func currentUser() -> FUser {
        return FUser()
    }
}
```

---

Or maybe you're looking for *singleton*, **static** instance of the class

```
class FUser: FObject {
    static var current = FUser()
}
```

then you can use it like this

```
FUser.current
```